# Hive query: select a column based on the condition another columns values match some specific values, then create the match result as a new column

Tags: sql, string, join, hive, hiveql

I have to some query and creat columns operations in HiveQL.

For example,

```
app      col1

app1     anybody love me?
app2     I hate u
app3     this hat is good
app4     I don't like this one
app5     oh my god
app6     damn you.
app7     such nice girl
app8     xxxxx
app9     pretty prefect
app10    don't love me.
app11    xxx anybody?
```

I want to match a keyword list like `['anybody', 'love', 'you', 'xxx', 'don't']` and select the matched keyword result as a new column, named `keyword` as follows:

```
app      keyword

app1     anybody, love
app4     I don't like this one
app6     damn you.
app8     xxx
app10    don't, love
app11    xxx
```

It seems that I have to use nested query.
The logic is kind of like selecting the matched result rows and setting a matched results which should be saved in a list or something like this as a new column.

But I am not familiar enough with the HiveQL.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: Thanks to @GMB, as a supplement, there is no duplicated situation in the `app_name` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the list of words to a table and join it with your table using pattern matching:

```
select t.app, k.keyword
from  mytable t
inner join (values ('anybody'), ('you'), ('xxx'), ('don''t')) as k(keyword)
    on t.col1 like conca('%', k.keyword, '%')
```

Note that this will duplicate `app` if more than one keyword matches on a phrase. You did not specify how you want to handle this use case.

In hive, you can also phrase this as:

```
select t.app, k.keyword
from  mytable t
inner join table(values 'anybody', 'you', 'xxx', 'don''t') as k(keyword)
    on t.col1 like conca('%', k.keyword, '%')
```

Comment: Could you give me a code example of `turn the list of words to a table`? I didn't search a suitable way. Thanks.

Comment: @BowenPeng: that's what the `values()` subquery does. I also added a second query to my answer that gives an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive you can use `stack` [UDTF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-stack(values)):

```
with keywords as (
select stack(4, --the number of tuples
'anybody', 'you', 'xxx', 'don\'t'
) as keyword
)

select t.app, k.keyword
from  mytable t
inner join keywords k
    on t.col1 like concat('%', k.keyword, '%')
```

Also for older versions of hive join using `like` will not work, use cross join with stack and filter in the WHERE:

```
from  mytable t
cross join keywords k
where t.col1 like concat('%', k.keyword, '%')
```