# PySpark: select a column based on the condition another columns values match some specific values, then create the match result as a new column

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I ask the similarity [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077780/hive-query-select-a-column-based-on-the-condition-another-columns-values-match) before, but for some reasons, It is sad that I have to reimplement it in `PySpark`.
For example,

```
app      col1

app1     anybody love me?
app2     I hate u
app3     this hat is good
app4     I don't like this one
app5     oh my god
app6     damn you.
app7     such nice girl
app8     xxxxx
app9     pretty prefect
app10    don't love me.
app11    xxx anybody?
```

I want to match a keyword list like `['anybody', 'love', 'you', 'xxx', 'don't']` and select the matched keyword result as a new column, named keyword as follows:

```
app      keyword

app1     [anybody, love]
app4     [don't]
app6     [you]
app8     [xxx]
app10    [don't, love]
app11    [xxx]
```

As the accepted answer the suitable way I can do is create a temporary dataframe which is converted by a string list then `inner join` these two dataframe together.
And `select` the rows of `app` and `keyword` that are matched in the condition.

```
-- Hiveql implementation
select t.app, k.keyword
from  mytable t
inner join (values ('anybody'), ('you'), ('xxx'), ('don''t')) as k(keyword)
    on t.col1 like conca('%', k.keyword, '%')
```

But I am not familiar with `PySpark` and awkward to reimplement it. 
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advances.

Comment: In pyspark you can easily write a UDF that get the col1 string and then its just simple python code (split the string) and do what u need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below two possible approaches:

**Option 1**

The first option is to use the dataframe API to implement the analogous join as in your previous question. Here we convert the `keywords` list into a dataframe and then join it with the large dataframe (*notice that we broadcast the small dataframe to ensure better performance*):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["app1", "anybody love me?"],
  ["app4", "I don't like this one"],
  ["app5", "oh my god"],
  ["app6", "damn you."],
  ["app7", "such nice girl"],
  ["app8", "xxxxx"],
  ["app10", "don't love me."]
]).toDF("app", "col1")

# create keywords dataframe
kdf = spark.createDataFrame([(k,) for k in keywords], "key string")

# +-----+
# |  key|
# +-----+
# |  xxx|
# |don't|
# +-----+

df.join(broadcast(kdf), df["col1"].contains(kdf["key"]), "inner")

# +-----+---------------------+-----+
# |app  |col1                 |key  |
# +-----+---------------------+-----+
# |app4 |I don't like this one|don't|
# |app8 |xxxxx                |xxx  |
# |app10|don't love me.       |don't|
# +-----+---------------------+-----+
```

The join condition is based on [contains](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.Column.contains) function of the Column class.

**Option 2**

You also can use PySpark high-order function [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) in combination with [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike) within an expr:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, expr, array

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["app1", "anybody love me?"],
  ["app4", "I don't like this one"],
  ["app5", "oh my god"],
  ["app6", "damn you."],
  ["app7", "such nice girl"],
  ["app8", "xxxxx"],
  ["app10", "don't love me."]
]).toDF("app", "col1")

keywords = ["xxx", "don't"]

df.withColumn("keywords", array([lit(k) for k in keywords])) \
  .withColumn("keywords", expr("filter(keywords, k -> col1 rlike k)")) \
  .where("size(keywords) > 0") \
  .show(10, False)

# +-----+---------------------+--------+
# |app  |col1                 |keywords|
# +-----+---------------------+--------+
# |app4 |I don't like this one|[don't] |
# |app8 |xxxxx                |[xxx]   |
# |app10|don't love me.       |[don't] |
# +-----+---------------------+--------+
```

*Explanation*

1. with `array([lit(k) for k in keywords])` we generate an array which contains the keywords that our search will be based on and then we append it to the existing dataframe using `withColumn`.
2. next with `expr("size(filter(keywords, k -> col1 rlike k)) > 0")` we go through the items of keywords trying to figure out if any of them is present in col1 text. If that is true `filter` will return one or more items and `size` will be greater than 0 which consists our `where` condition for retrieving the records.

Comment: SORRY to respond to you such late. I tried the **option one** as follows but didn't I get what I really want.

Comment: @Bowen no problem at all, can you elaborate a bit more? What is the expected output? for instance given Option 2 is this the expected output?

Comment: I tried the **option one** code as follows and here is the result,  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BdZbbgkkKT/. And the **option two** code in my real developing environment get such error messages, https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pWbSgvTJy8/. AND SORRY AGAIN, I would like to post it all but press the enter button by accident so just left a bad comment. :(

Comment: So given the keywords ["xxx", "don't"] we search for text in col1 that contains one them. In the example above app4 and app8 satisfy that condition.

Comment: @Bowen right now you are calling `df.show()` which is printing the original dataframe. The join transformation will not modify the original df since RDDs are imutable.  In order to get the final results that you need to do `final_df =  df.join(broadcast(kdf), df["col1"].contains(kdf["key"]), "inner")` and then `final_df.show()`

Comment: As for Option 2 the error [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pWbSgvTJy8/) says that the column with name `col` was not found maybe you mistyped it because there is not such a column. Try to copy paste the code again

Comment: And one more question for **option two** cause I want to only display the matched keywords in the `keywords` column, which should by like follows, https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yFVZmvyxBf/. And how to fix it.

Comment: And demand has a little changed. The value in the `keyword` should be a string list that shows all matched keywords so how to code it properly. Cause the answer only shows one matched keyword in the `keyword` column/

Comment: @Bowen the option 2 does exactly that it will store all the matches into `keywords` col